# Is it possible to render a widget under a SingleChildScrollView that goes outside its boundries?

Tags: flutter

I'm using the plugin `fl_chart` which allows to display some bars and when you tap them a popup is displayed. Example:
[image]
[image]

If the popup is big it will go outside the boundaries of the parent, for example if I have a card, the popup will be displayed over it:

[image]

Until here that is my expected behavior and is achieved with a code like this simplified for the question:

```dart
          Card(
            elevation: 8,
            shape:
                RoundedRectangleBorder(borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(30)),
            child: Container(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8),
              child: Row(
                  children: [
                     Expanded(
                        child: BarChart(
                              _getData(mySrc)
                          ),
                       ),
                     ),
                  ),
```

The number of bars that I will display is dynamic, therefore I want to make my row scrollable so I wrapped my row with a SingleChildScrollView:

```dart
                              child: Row(
                                children: [
                                  Expanded(
                                    child: SingleChildScrollView(
                                      scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
                                      child: SizedBox(
                                        width: 400,
                                        child: BarChart(
                                          _getData(mySrc),
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                    ),
                                  ),
```

And scrolling works as expected, but now it seems the popup is not allowed to go beyond the boundaries of the SingleChildScrollView:
[image]

Is there anyway I can keep the scrolling without damaging the popup generated by the `fl_chart` plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
SingleChildScrollView(
    clipBehavior: Clip.none,
```

if it doesnt work you can try to set padding top to the SingleChildScrollView and make some extra space so popup doesnt get clipped

Comment: Thank you, that did indeed work with only the `clipBheavior`